# Voltage drop across an inductor in a $RL$ circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, inductance

for a circuit that has a resistor (resistance $R$), and a
inductor (inductance $L$), that are connected in series to a source of AC electromotance.

How do I find the voltage drop across the inductor in term of the component values, $R$ and $L$, the source electromotance $E$ and the source frequency, $ω$?

Comment: While this is straightforward in the frequency domain I think a good physical picture is obtained if you write Kirchhoff’s voltage law in tome domain and take the Fourier transform

Answer (score 0):

The basic formula for finding the potential drop is $V=X_{L}I$ ----(1);

Where $X_L$ is the inductive reactance

and I is current

Step 1: To find $X_L$

its simple $X_L$=$\omega$L

Step 2: To find current I

In LCR circuit we find net reactance which is similar to net resistance

${Z}^{2}$=$R^2$+${X_{L}}^2$

Then we have I=V/Z.

Now you can substitute the values of I and $X_L$ and substitute in eqn (1).